# Move REDIS data between memory and disk

Tags: linux, memory, redis, redis-server, swapfile

REDIS is a memory database, it's easy to fill the entire memory though.
My question is, how can I expand the space by storing some data on disk?

Can the memory be expanded with GNU/Linux swap?
What's the easiest and most effective option?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately opensource version of Redis don't support extending memory with disk storage. Some options you can consider are:

Redis on Flash - https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/concepts/memory-architecture/redis-flash/

This is a commercial version and will cost the wallet.

KeyDB flash - https://github.com/EQ-Alpha/KeyDB/wiki/Enhanced-FLASH-Support-(PRO)

KeyDB is pitted against Redis as an alternative. However, flash support is commercial again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that keydb data can expand to flash.

see https://docs.keydb.dev/docs/flash/

> FLASH storage enables you to expand memory capacity greatly without a huge compromise on performance. Best of all your data persists to the FLASH memory as it is written eliminating the need for AOF/RDB files. KeyDB on FLASH is great for applications where memory is limited or too costly for the application. It is also a great option for databases that often near or exceed their maxmemory limit.

There is nothing about a commercial option.